# box2d meters doesn't work - libgdx

Tags: position, libgdx, box2d

It seems that everytime I define body definition, I need to put large values of so called "meters" in order for the body to be positioned where I want. It seems that it requires from me pixels values(!).

Another thing is the point (0,0) is located in the bottom-left corner of the screen when I define things in box2d.

Here is a code of one of my bodies:

```
package com.david.objects;

import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef.BodyType;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.PolygonShape;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World;
import com.david.gameworld.GameRenderer;
import com.david.helpers.AssetsLoader;

public class CatapultArm extends ObjectInWorld{

    public CatapultArm(World world) {
        super(world);
        initiate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void initiate() {
        //The Body
        bodyDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
        bodyDef.position.set(154, GameRenderer.FLOOR_HEIGHT);

        // The shape
        PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
        shape.setAsBox(11, 91);

        // The fixture
        fixtureDef.shape = shape;
        fixtureDef.restitution = .80f;
        fixtureDef.friction = .75f;
        sprite = AssetsLoader.armSprite;
        body = world.createBody(bodyDef);
        body.setUserData(sprite);
        fixture = body.createFixture(fixtureDef);
    }
}
```

ObjectInWorld.java

```
package com.david.objects;

import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Fixture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.FixtureDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World;

public abstract class ObjectInWorld {

    protected BodyDef bodyDef;
    protected Body body;
    protected World world;
    protected FixtureDef fixtureDef;
    protected Fixture fixture;
    protected Sprite sprite;
    protected ObjectInWorld(World world) {
        this.world = world;
        bodyDef = new BodyDef();
        fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
        sprite = new Sprite();
    }

    protected void initiate() {

    }
    public float getX() {
        return body.getPosition().x;
    }
    public float getY() {
        return body.getPosition().y;
    }
    public Body getBody() {
        return body;
    }
}
```

Can you please tell me what's wrong and what is the right way to define things and positions in box2d?

Comment: If you create a body box2D reads the dimensions as meters. But by default, 1 pixel equals 1 meter. This means if you create a body like you did in your example, your box would be 11*91 Meter. Normally you would defined a variable to adjust this, so that for example 100 pixel equal 1 meter. There are a couple of tutorials on YouTube (e.g: http://youtu.be/tm2vQ8J4-kI)

Comment: The problem is that the dimensions are fine. I defined the box to be 11*91 but it's not smaller/bigger than what I have expected and that's the problem.

Comment: I would create a little debug output.

So pick an object to output the positions, and have it render the screen position (in pixels) and the box2d position (in the world). That will help you sort out what you're doing wrong.